# reader-writer and inter-process communication designing

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, ipc

I want to write a program, one module is:

I have two processes, process A is responsible for receiving packets using `recvfrom()` or `recv`
and another process B keep on some other things.

whenever process A receives a packet, it should immediately extract some information from the packet and tell the information to process B. And B needs to immediately stop what it is doing and read the information.

This is like a tcp stack, let me say, process A is responsible for receiving  data packets or ack packets, and process B is responsible for sending packets. when Process A receives a data packet, process B should read the data packet, update seq number and ack_seq number for its next outgoing packet.

Anyway, my idea is process A and B should share a structure variable, and there is a lock on the varialbe. B keeps on reading the varialbe, when A receives a packet, it lock the variable, thus B is blocked. After A modify the variable, A unlock it and B get to read the variable and then continue to do its own job. Pseudo code is like

```
struct SHARE shared_variable;
pid=fork();
if(pid==0) {  // process B
        while(1){
         lock(shared_variable);
         k=read(shared_variable);
         unlock(shared_variable);
         do_something(k);  
         }
       }

 if(pid>0){ // process A
       while(1){
       recv();
       lock(shared_variable);
       modify(shared_variable);
       unlock(shared_variable);
       }
   }
```

I'm not familiar with inter-process communication and network programming
my question is:
     1 is the structure of my pseudo code ok? are there better solutions?
     2 what kind of IPC style should I use for the shared variable
     3 I only knows some theory, are there any concrete sample source codes?

```
thanks!
```

Comment: You can use `socketpair` for IPC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461106/socketpair-in-c-unix

Comment: wow, thanks, but so long a time just one reply, and it seems it is not a common IPC method, are my requirements so pecular?

Comment: Not in particular. Your question is a bit vague. You ask a general question, and then imply a logic of using shared memory (which if far from being trivial). I suggest to start with something simpler...