# How to write a value to parent process from child process?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fd[2];
int check = pipe(fd);

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int read_int=0;

    pid=fork();

    if(pid==0)
    {
        execl("./getvalue.out","getvalue.out",(char *)0);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0],&read_int,sizeof(read_int));
        printf("Receive: %d\n",read_int);
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    wait(0);
}
```

And this is getvalue.cpp: (for creating a **getvalue.out**)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    int write_int=100;
    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1],&write_int,sizeof(write_int));
    close(fd[1]);
}
```

So `read_int` always be `0` instead of value of `100` received from child process using `execl()`. I guess the problem is they are not sharing the pipe?

Comment: This is actually C, not C++ (even though it might be compilable by a C++ compiler all the code shown here is using C APIs and is written in a C-style)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461106/socketpair-in-c-unix

Answer (score 0):

Your getvalue code's fd[] doesn't point to the pipe anymore. Pass the fd[1] value in parent  as a command line parameter to the child's process.