# Why should we dup and close the original fd here

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am currently reading Python 2.7's multiprocessing code. 
I am confused about the implementation of [connection.Pipe](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py).

It uses the following code to create a duplex pipe.

```
s1, s2 = socket.socketpair()
s1.setblocking(True)
s2.setblocking(True)
c1 = _multiprocessing.Connection(os.dup(s1.fileno()))
c2 = _multiprocessing.Connection(os.dup(s2.fileno()))
s1.close()
s2.close()
```

But why should we firstly `dup` `s1` and `s2`'s fileno and close them instead of using them directly?

I think it is quite different from [the following implementation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461106/socketpair-in-c-unix) which close **only** parent on child process(and child on parent process) **after** `fork` is called.

Comment: The socket is for the two ends of the pipe to communicate with each other, not for the parent to communicate with either child.

Comment: Presumably, `s1.close()` will close the fd as a side effect (or, rather, part of its primary function.)  `dup`ing the fd before closing `s1` is a lot cleaner than trying to surgically remove the closure of the fd from the `close` method.