# Why does socketpair() return 2 sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, ipc

`socketpair()` is almost always used in companion with `fork()`. It returns 2 sockets, and after a call to `fork()`, we got 4. In most examples I have seen, one of the two sockets in each process is closed and the other is preserved immediately after `fork()`. It seems that there are always 2 useless sockets. Given this situation, why doesn't `sockpair()` just return a socket that connects to itself? This way, after a call to `fork()`, every socket is in use.

Is there a `socketpair()` equivalent that returns a socket that connects to itself?

If not, is it because such a socket is not possible(or easy) to be implemented?

If it is possible, how can I implement it?

Edit: I think this question is different from [Socketpair() in C/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461106/socketpair-in-c-unix).
It didn't explain why there are always 2 useless sockets to be closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socketpair() in C/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461106/socketpair-in-c-unix)

Comment: @IłyaBursov I think this question is different from Socketpair() in C/Unix. It didn't explain why there are always 2 useless sockets to be closed.

Comment: they are not useless, they represent different ends of pipe, while usually you close one of them - it is not the only use case, you can continue to use both sockets in the same process for example, and this is explained in linked question

Comment: @IłyaBursov I know they're usable, but in most cases they are not used. For simplicity one socket is just ok. Isn't it?

Comment: spare tire in your car is not used 99.9% of the time, for simplicity lets car manufacturing stop supplying it?

Comment: `fork()` doesn't create a new socket.  It duplicates a file descriptor for the same socket.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the underlying reason is that the concepts of `socketpair` were taken from `pipe`. A pipe is an unidirectional channel, so the `pipe` call creates a pair of end points, one for reading and one for writing.

When you create a pair of sockets, you expect to later have a pair of processes or threads, each one using one end of the pair, exactly the same as `pipe` is used, except that you have a bi-directional channel. But the key is that what is written on one end point is read on the other one, no matter how many processes or threads are used. You could imagine that one single process *posts* requests on one socket, and, provided a synchronisation tool like a mutex is used, many workers each reading a *request* to process at the moment it holds the mutex.